# While not "A" , unless "AB"

Tags: python

While parsing an ASCII file, I want to perform some operations on a section of lines.

The length of the section will vary, so I made a while loop that should continue until I reach a line starting with "A", indicating that the section has ended.
However, within the section there will be some lines starting with "AB", which I want to include.

So I'm looking for something like:
while not line[0] == "A", unless line[:2] == "AB"

I.e. "AA", "AC", "A$" or "A-whatever" should break the loop, but "AB" should not.

I'm a novice and haven't found the right search terms for a nice clean solution to this, though I'm sure one must exist, or do I need to resort to regex?

Edit:
As requested here is a sample:

```
*SIGNAL* $$$1 2 -2 ; 
R1.2                            U1.36                           
3.1    3.635  0 0.3048 1792  THERMAL 
14.92  14     65 0.3048 1792  THERMAL 

*SIGNAL* $$$2 2 -2 ; 
R1.1                            U1.40                           
3.1    2.365  0 0.3048 1792  THERMAL 
18.984 14     65 0.3048 1792  THERMAL 

*SIGNAL* $$$3 2 -2 ; 
U1.16                           U1.22                           
24.064 26.7   0 0.3048 1792  THERMAL 
18     29.2   1 0.3048 1280 STANDARDVIA THERMAL  TEARDROP N 90 90 
17.968 29.168 1 0.3048 1536 
17.968 26.7   65 0.3048 768  THERMAL  TEARDROP P 90 90 
U1.16                           R3.2                            
24.064 26.7   1 0.3048 1280  THERMAL  TEARDROP N 90 90 
29     26.7   1 0.3048 1536 
29.7   26     1 0.3048 1536 
33.4   26     1 0.3048 1536 
33.4   26.035 65 0.3048 768  THERMAL  TEARDROP P 90 90 
U1.22                           U1.2                            
17.968 26.7   0 0.3048 1792  THERMAL 
21.016 14     65 0.3048 1792  THERMAL 
U1.26                           U1.22                           
13.142 24.922 0 0.3048 1792  THERMAL 
17.968 26.7   65 0.3048 1792  THERMAL 
R2.2                            U1.2                            
17     3.65   0 0.3048 1792  THERMAL 
21.016 14     65 0.3048 1792  THERMAL 

*SIGNAL* $$$4 2 -2 ; 
R2.1                            U1.4                            
17     2.35   0 0.3048 1792  THERMAL 
23.048 14     65 0.3048 1792  THERMAL 

*SIGNAL* $$$5 2 -2 ; 
R3.1                            U1.6                            
33.4   24.765 0 0.3048 1792  THERMAL 
25.842 15.778 65 0.3048 1792  THERMAL 

*TESTPOINT*
...
```

In this case, the next section is called "*TESTPOINT*", but that will vary. The only known character is the beginning "*", so unfortunately that includes all the "*SIGNAL*"-lines as well.

Comment: It might help to show a few lines of your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use "or"

```
while line[0] != "A" or line[:2] == "AB":
    # your code here
```

Comment: Please see my comment to Óscar López.

Answer (score 3):

This would be perfect for a regular expression.

For example,

```
^A(?!B).*
```

will match a line that starts with A and does not have a B afterwards.

You could probably match entire sections this way, for example (assuming that you want to match everything from `Z` to `A` (unless `AB`), then

```
(?s)^Z.*?^A(?!B)
```

would match that. If you can specify your problem more precisely, it's possible to design a more specific regex.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you try this:

```
while line[0] != 'A' or line[:2] == 'AB':
    # code
```

Explanation:

- This part: `line[0] != 'A' or` says: if the line doesn't start with `'A'`, then keep iterating. But if it *does* start with `'A'`, it'll check the next condition before deciding what to do next.
- Finally, this part: `line[0] != 'A'` says, if the line starts with `'AB'`, then keep iterating. But if the line started with `'A'` and was followed by anything else, then break. And that's exactly what you want!.

Comment: Will this not require every line to start with "AB"?
This is not the case and also some lines are empty.

Comment: Nope, because it is a "or", not a "and".  So to execute, either your line starts with "AB", or it doesn't start with "A".

Comment: @Lest I updated my answer with a detailed explanation, please check it :)

Comment: @Lest I also removed the emptiness check, if your input can contain blank lines, it doesn't make sense. It's hard to know what you needed, because you never posted how exactly are you reading each line...

Comment: Thank you @Fukiyel, my bad. Your solution worked nicely.
So simple once you see it. :)

Comment: Thanks @ÓscarLópez, upvoted. :)
(Though it won't show, since I'm too new.)

Comment: @Lest I think you're confusing "accepting" an answer with "upvoting" it. You can up vote all the answers you want now, but only accept one. See this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Ideally, you should accept the best answer.